# Deserializing JSON array containing objects with an array using GSON

Tags: json, gson

I have a JSON response representing a Band that looks like this:

```
[
 {
  "Picture": {
  "Small": "someurl
  "Medium": "someurl",
  "Large": "someurl",
  "XLarge": "someurl"
},
"Name": "Tokyo Control Tower",
"Guid": "TCT",
"ID": 15
 }
]
```

And I'm trying to use GSON to deserialize it into a class called SearchResults which contains a list of Bands. My SearchResults and Band classes look like this:

```
public class SearchResults {
    public List<Band> results;
}

public class Band {
    @SerializedName("Name")
    public String name;

    @SerializedName("Guid")
    public String guid;

    @SerializedName("ID")
    public Integer id;

    @SerializedName("Picture")
    List<Photo> pictures;

}
```

In my code I try to convert the json string like this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        SearchResults results = gson.fromJson(result, SearchResults.class);
        Band band = results.results.get(0);
        bandName.setText(band.name);
    }
```

When I run this code, I get an error from GSON saying Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY. Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: `pictures` is a list in your class definition (i.e. a JSON array), but it's a JSON object in the sample JSON you gave. Did you meant to either make it an array in the JSON, or create a "Pictures" class or map to represent the various picture sizes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple issues.

First and foremost, what is causing the error you post is that you are telling Gson that your JSON represents an object (`SearchResults`) when it doesn't; your JSON is an array of objects (specifically, an object you're mapping to your Java `Band` class).

The correct way to do this is via:

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Band>>(){}.getType();
Collection<Band> bands = gson.fromJson(jsonString, collectionType);
```

Once you do that you're going to have a problem in that in your Java class you're saying that "Picture" in your JSON is an array of `Photo` objects when in fact it's not; it's a single object.